# Deprecated content in JDK

Tags: java

Why is there still deprecated content in JDK like `Thread.stop()`?

On the documentation site [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()) I can see the method is

> @Deprecated(since="1.2")

Since 1.2!

Also, there is a note:

```
This method is inherently unsafe
```

So why is it still there? The presence of deprecated code can potentially lead to many issues.

Comment: "*So why is it still there?*" Backwards compatibility.

Comment: Not everyone has a budget and time to upgrade their application to the newer version of Java.

Comment: @Michael but it's not always like that. Take a look at `Thread.suspend()` - "This API element is subject to removal in a future version", so some of the legacy code is being removed

Comment: @WLTY - Eventually, everything marked **deprecated** will be removed. Until then, they will be maintained with **deprecated** status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a whole page from Oracle talking about deprecation in APIs [if you want to read about it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20%40Deprecated%20annotation%20to,code%20uses%20that%20program%20element.&text=Thus%2C%20using%20the%20%40Deprecated%20annotation,on%20the%20%40deprecated%20Javadoc%20tag.), but here is a good snippet which sums up why deprecated functions are still in Java:

> Deprecation is a reasonable choice in all these cases because it preserves "backward compatibility" while encouraging developers to change to the new API. Also, the deprecation comments help developers decide when to move to the new API, and so should briefly mention the technical reasons for deprecation.

Eventually, it will be removed, but until there is enough confidence that people are not using programs that still utilse `Thread.stop()`, they will keep it in there, and just let people know that there are much better options to choose from.